# Connect a MySQL db that has SSH tunneling with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2010

I want to connect a MySQL database with Visual Studio 2010 server explorer so I can work on my website. I installed the MySQL connector but that connector is only for a MySQL database that doesn't have SSH tunneling. Is there some connector for this? (althou I think I would've found it by now.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have to do is choose a ssh client (I like putty - http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/)

Then when you connect to the remote host tunnel the mysql port from the remote machine to your local one (check in the documentation)

After you have done this, then use the server explorer and connect to localhost.

Alternatively, take a look at MySQL Workbench (http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) it has SSH tunneling built in